# what's the way to move file in ipython notebook?

Tags: ipython

I wrote a file in ipython notebook and I saved it in my computer as test.ipynb
When I transfer this file to another computer and tried to open it nothing appeared.
What's happen?

Comment: Is it a plain notebook or contains custom javascript?

Answer (score 0):

How are you launching the notebook? When you save an .ipynb file to a specific directory on your computer if launching from command line you need to launch the ipython notebook from that directory in order to pull in the .ipynb file that you've saved.

Example: test.ipynb file is saved to the \Desktop directory. When launching the notebook from command line you would need to:

```
cd Desktop
ipython notebook
```

I know if you launch that way when the browser session spawns it'll pull in the .ipynb file that you have saved as an already created notebook.

[This works too](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/notebook.html#starting-the-notebook-server)